# Java: convert list of objects to something else

Tags: java

I have a class that has a list of Events.

```
public class EventScheduler{

     List<Event> event

}

public class Event{

     private String text;
     private int timestamp;

}
```

I have an EventView, it takes an Event as a constructor and has getters and no setters.

It is basically allows subset of variables set in event to be viewed, whilst acting in a similar fashion to Event.

```
public class EventView{

     public EventView(Event event){
         this.event = event;
     }

     public String getText(){
         return event.getText();
     }

     //no timestamp getter as its not allowed for this view object.
}
```

So with this setup, what is the quickest way to convert a `List<Event>` to `List<EventView>`?
Or some kind of alternative.

Comment: as answered below, you have to instantiate an object using "new".

Comment: You write a for-loop that iterators over the list of Events and creates en EventView object for each. With Java 8 there are alternative syntaxes than a for-loop to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Java 8:

```
List<EventView> views = events.stream()
                              .map(EventView::new)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each `Event` and create an `EventView` for it, then pass it to a list:

```
List<EventView> eventViewList = new ArrayList<EventView>();
if(eventList != null) {
   for(Event event : eventList) {
       EventView eventView = new EventView(event);
       eventViewList.add(eventView);
   }
}
```